# Changing the source IP address when sending a UDP message in node.js

Tags: node.js, udp, ip, spoofing

Is there a way to manually set a different source IP address when sending a UDP packet (IP spoofing)?

I built a UDP proxy that manually filters some packets that are being sent by third-party clients, and then proxies the right ones to a different server. Currently all the messages being proxied to the final server have the proxy's IP address, while I'd like to keep the original client IP address.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that is not possible within Node.JS, you can't addressing a address that you aren't associated. Instead you can try a tool called `nemesis` his propose is to check security and to test intrusion detection.

http://nemesis.sourceforge.net/